# Secure Named Shared Memory on Windows so only specific processes can open

Tags: windows, winapi, ipc

Is there a way to set the permissions with Named Shared Memory in Windows so that the access control is done by process rather than by user?  I'd like to have one program create the memory, pass a handle or pass back a PID so that the client process can access the memory.  All other processes should be denied access. Thanks

Comment: There wouldn't be any point.  Another process (running as the same user or as an administrator) could read the contents of the client process virtual address space using ReadProcessMemory, or load and run its own code within the client process, or attach to the client process as a debugger.

Comment: It may be possible to read process memory, but knowing where the data is is a lot harder. The data is better formatted in a named shared memory block and easier to decode.

Answer (score 5):

Access control is only by security principals, which can be users, groups, computers, and the like.

If you have an object that you want shared with another process, you can use [DuplicateHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Is it possible to browse kernel objects in the global space?  A random filename may be enough to protect the memory.

Comment: You can use WinObj to browser the kernel namespace: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657.aspx

Comment: Let's say that I create a shared memory segment as a service, ie "SYSTEM" username.  Can I then pass a DuplicateHandle handle to a user process, or will that throw a permission exception?

Comment: You can duplicate a handle to any process you can get an appropriate handle to.

Answer (score 1):

No, because processes are not security principles.

Instead, use an unnamed file mapping and give the client process a copy of the handle using [DuplicateHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724251%28v=vs.85%29).

Comment: Can I pass the handle copy to another user?

Comment: Yes, if the server is running in an administrative context.  (If not, there may still be ways to do it, but it would be much more complicated.)